# How to get strings containing space without gets() in C?

Tags: c, string, gcc, scanf, gets

When getting strings which contain spaces with `scanf()`, it assigns only the input given before space. Like if I give "hello world" as input. Only "hello" gets stored in the variable. I know its quiet natural with `scanf()`. When I use `gets()`, it works fine. But gcc reports that `gets()` is deprecated. It also gives a warning that `gets()` is dangerous and shouldn't be used. So without `gets()` how to get strings with space? Are there other alternative functions?

Comment: `char str[256]; fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` -- Note that `fgets` consumes and stores `\n` at the end of `str` (assuming there is space for it).

Comment: What is the second argument? Is it the maximum number of characters or the required number of characters or anything else?

Comment: `char str[256] = {0}; scanf("%255[^\n]%*c", str);`

Comment: It is the maximum number of characters to store in `str`, thus, unlike `gets`, avoids a buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks Cool Guy and BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`

To take input from the user, in place of `FILE* stream`, use the standard input `stdin`

```
fgets (str, 60, stdin)
```

Comment: With that can I get input from stdin?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, you can